# Regular expression group matching not working

Tags: c#, regex

What am I missing here?

```
Regex _validityRegEx = new Regex(@"^(<minStay>.{2})\/(<maxStay>.{2})$");
Match validityMatch = _validityRegEx.Match("--/3M);
```

I want two groups one containing the first two characters and one containing the second two after the `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use next pattern (you have missed `?`):

```
@"^(?<minStay>.{2})/(?<maxStay>.{2})$"
```

You may acces to groups like this:

```
var minStay = validityMatch.Groups["minStay"].Value
var maxStay = validityMatch.Groups["maxStay"].Value
```

Comment: @Liam From documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx you will always get only at least one group (even if there is no match). So please use named groups to get what you need.

Comment: Cheers Petro, I get what you mean.